# How to call multiple APIView in one single web page as a list of items?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I am in the process of developing a quiz project using django rest framework, and within that requirement, I need to list every table in one single page. Below is the code snippet.

```
class QuizList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'adminView.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
        return Response({'quiz': queryset})


class AnswerList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'adminView.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Answer.objects.all()
        return Response({'answer': queryset})


class QuestionList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'adminView.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Question.objects.all()
        return Response({'question': queryset})
```

In the above snippet, I am able to list the very fist class "QuizView" in my web page. But other than that, when I am trying to add other APIViews, they are simply not happening. Below is the HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin View</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {% for quizez in quiz %}

    <a href="" onclick="">{{ quizez.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>

<ul>
    {% for questions in question %}
    <li>{{ questions.label }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
    {% for answers in answer %}
    <li>{{ answer.text }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to put all the for loops within a single "ul", but even that didn't work. Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not only one view class?

```
class AllView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'adminView.html'

    def get(self, request):
        quiz_queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
        answer_queryset = Answer.objects.all()
        question_queryset = Question.objects.all()
        return Response({
            'quiz': quiz_queryset,
            'answer': answer_queryset,
            'question': question_queryset
        })
```

Comment: Thank you Zaipa. That answers my query precisely. we can conclude the thread here now.